# The type or namespace name 'IndexModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, .net-5, abp, visual-studio-2022

I am getting several of the following errors after compiling my ABP Commercial based solution.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IndexModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    ClientsLink.IdentityServer  D:\Century\Internal\MyProduct\MyProduct\aspnet-core\src\MyProduct.IdentityServer\obj\Debug\net5.0\Razor\Pages\Index.cshtml.g.cs 215 Active
```

I can't tell if it is a bug in the Visual Studio 2022 application, the Roslyn compiler, or something to do with Razor, but it is intermittent. I think the key thing to point out is that the `Index.cshtml.g.cs` file is not in my solution. It is some kind of autogenerated temporary file created when I build (Note the path).

Here are the contents of the file:

```
#pragma checksum "D:\Century\Internal\MyProduct\MyProduct\aspnet-core\src\MyProduct.IdentityServer\Pages\Index.cshtml" "{ff1816ec-aa5e-4d10-87f7-6f4963833460}" "f43e9fc593b31efe4f68ec9898517ecb634d6927"
// <auto-generated/>
#pragma warning disable 1591
[assembly: global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorCompiledItemAttribute(typeof(AspNetCore.Pages_Index), @"mvc.1.0.razor-page", @"/Pages/Index.cshtml")]
namespace AspNetCore
{
    #line hidden
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
#nullable restore
#line 2 "D:\Century\Internal\MyProduct\MyProduct\aspnet-core\src\MyProduct.IdentityServer\Pages\Index.cshtml"
using MyProduct.Localization;

#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
#nullable restore
#line 3 "D:\Century\Internal\MyProduct\MyProduct\aspnet-core\src\MyProduct.IdentityServer\Pages\Index.cshtml"
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization;

#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
#nullable restore
#line 4 "D:\Century\Internal\MyProduct\MyProduct\aspnet-core\src\MyProduct.IdentityServer\Pages\Index.cshtml"
using Volo.Abp.Users;

#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
    [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorSourceChecksumAttribute(@"SHA1", @"f43e9fc593b31efe4f68ec9898517ecb634d6927", @"/Pages/Index.cshtml")]
    [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorSourceChecksumAttribute(@"SHA1", @"25152d795852518cc499282e563bc297efeed2a9", @"/Pages/_ViewImports.cshtml")]
    public class Pages_Index : global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Page
    {
        private static readonly global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute __tagHelperAttribute_0 = new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute("asp-controller", "Logout", global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.HtmlAttributeValueStyle.DoubleQuotes);
        private static readonly global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute __tagHelperAttribute_1 = new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute("asp-action", "Index", global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.HtmlAttributeValueStyle.DoubleQuotes);
        private static readonly global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute __tagHelperAttribute_2 = new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute("asp-area", "Account", global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.HtmlAttributeValueStyle.DoubleQuotes);
        private static readonly global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute __tagHelperAttribute_3 = new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagHelperAttribute("class", new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString("text-center"), global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.HtmlAttributeValueStyle.DoubleQuotes);
        #line hidden
        #pragma warning disable 0649
        private global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperExecutionContext __tagHelperExecutionContext;
        #pragma warning restore 0649
        private global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner __tagHelperRunner = new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner();
        #pragma warning disable 0169
        private string __tagHelperStringValueBuffer;
        #pragma warning restore 0169
        private global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperScopeManager __backed__tagHelperScopeManager = null;
        private global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperScopeManager __tagHelperScopeManager
        {
            get
            {
                if (__backed__tagHelperScopeManager == null)
                {
                    __backed__tagHelperScopeManager = new global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperScopeManager(StartTagHelperWritingScope, EndTagHelperWritingScope);
                }
                return __backed__tagHelperScopeManager;
            }
        }
        private global::Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bootstrap.TagHelpers.Grid.AbpRowTagHelper __Volo_Abp_AspNetCore_Mvc_UI_Bootstrap_TagHelpers_Grid_AbpRowTagHelper;
        private global::Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bootstrap.TagHelpers.Grid.AbpColumnTagHelper __Volo_Abp_AspNetCore_Mvc_UI_Bootstrap_TagHelpers_Grid_AbpColumnTagHelper;
        private global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.AnchorTagHelper __Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_TagHelpers_AnchorTagHelper;
        private global::Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bootstrap.TagHelpers.Button.AbpLinkButtonTagHelper __Volo_Abp_AspNetCore_Mvc_UI_Bootstrap_TagHelpers_Button_AbpLinkButtonTagHelper;
        #pragma warning disable 1998
        public async override global::System.Threading.Tasks.Task ExecuteAsync()
        {
            WriteLiteral("<div>\n    ");
            __tagHelperExecutionContext = __tagHelperScopeManager.Begin("abp-row", global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag, "f43e9fc593b31efe4f68ec9898517ecb634d69275150", async() => {
                WriteLiteral("\n        ");
                __tagHelperExecutionContext = __tagHelperScopeManager.Begin("abp-column", global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag, "f43e9fc593b31efe4f68ec9898517ecb634d69275417", async() => {
                    WriteLiteral("\n            <i class=\"fa fa-user d-block\" style=\"color: #12b900; font-size: 10em;\"></i>\n");
                    WriteLiteral("            ");
                    __tagHelperExecutionContext = __tagHelperScopeManager.Begin("a", global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag, "f43e9fc593b31efe4f68ec9898517ecb634d69275831", async() => {
#nullable restore
#line (13,100)-(13,111) 6 "D:\Century\Internal\MyProduct\MyProduct\aspnet-core\src\MyProduct.IdentityServer\Pages\Index.cshtml"
Write(L["Logout"]);

#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
                    }
                    );
                    __Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_TagHelpers_AnchorTagHelper = CreateTagHelper<global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.AnchorTagHelper>();
                    __tagHelperExecutionContext.Add(__Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_TagHelpers_AnchorTagHelper);
                    __Volo_Abp_AspNetCore_Mvc_UI_Bootstrap_TagHelpers_Button_AbpLinkButtonTagHelper = CreateTagHelper<global::Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bootstrap.TagHelpers.Button.AbpLinkButtonTagHelper>();
                    __tagHelperExecutionContext.Add(__Volo_Abp_AspNetCore_Mvc_UI_Bootstrap_TagHelpers_Button_AbpLinkButtonTagHelper);
#nullable restore
#line 13 "D:\Century\Internal\MyProduct\MyProduct\aspnet-core\src\MyProduct.IdentityServer\Pages\Index.cshtml"
__Volo_Abp_AspNetCore_Mvc_UI_Bootstrap_TagHelpers_Button_AbpLinkButtonTagHelper.ButtonType = global::Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bootstrap.TagHelpers.Button.AbpButtonType.Primary;

#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
                    __tagHelperExecutionContext.AddTagHelperAttribute("abp-button", __Volo_Abp_AspNetCore_Mvc_UI_Bootstrap_TagHelpers_Button_AbpLinkButtonTagHelper.ButtonType, global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.HtmlAttributeValueStyle.DoubleQuotes);
                    __Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_TagHelpers_AnchorTagHelper.Controller = (string)__tagHelperAttribute_0.Value;
                    __tagHelperExecutionContext.AddTagHelperAttribute(__tagHelperAttribute_0);
                    __Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_TagHelpers_AnchorTagHelper.Action = (string)__tagHelperAttribute_1.Value;
                    __tagHelperExecutionContext.AddTagHelperAttribute(__tagHelperAttribute_1);
                    __Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_TagHelpers_AnchorTagHelper.Area = (string)__tagHelperAttribute_2.Value;
                    __tagHelperExecutionContext.AddTagHelperAttribute(__tagHelperAttribute_2);
                    await __tagHelperRunner.RunAsync(__tagHelperExecutionContext);
                    if (!__tagHelperExecutionContext.Output.IsContentModified)
                    {
                        await __tagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync();
                    }
                    Write(__tagHelperExecutionContext.Output);
                    __tagHelperExecutionContext = __tagHelperScopeManager.End();
                    WriteLiteral("\n        ");
                }
                );
                __Volo_Abp_AspNetCore_Mvc_UI_Bootstrap_TagHelpers_Grid_AbpColumnTagHelper = CreateTagHelper<global::Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bootstrap.TagHelpers.Grid.AbpColumnTagHelper>();
                __tagHelperExecutionContext.Add(__Volo_Abp_AspNetCore_Mvc_UI_Bootstrap_TagHelpers_Grid_AbpColumnTagHelper);
#nullable restore
#line 10 "D:\Century\Internal\MyProduct\MyProduct\aspnet-core\src\MyProduct.IdentityServer\Pages\Index.cshtml"
__Volo_Abp_AspNetCore_Mvc_UI_Bootstrap_TagHelpers_Grid_AbpColumnTagHelper.SizeMd = global::Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bootstrap.TagHelpers.Grid.ColumnSize._3;

#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
                __tagHelperExecutionContext.AddTagHelperAttribute("size-md", __Volo_Abp_AspNetCore_Mvc_UI_Bootstrap_TagHelpers_Grid_AbpColumnTagHelper.SizeMd, global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.HtmlAttributeValueStyle.DoubleQuotes);
                __tagHelperExecutionContext.AddHtmlAttribute(__tagHelperAttribute_3);
                await __tagHelperRunner.RunAsync(__tagHelperExecutionContext);
                if (!__tagHelperExecutionContext.Output.IsContentModified)
                {
                    await __tagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync();
                }
                Write(__tagHelperExecutionContext.Output);
                __tagHelperExecutionContext = __tagHelperScopeManager.End();
                WriteLiteral("\n        ");
                __tagHelperExecutionContext = __tagHelperScopeManager.Begin("abp-column", global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag, "f43e9fc593b31efe4f68ec9898517ecb634d692710199", async() => {
                    WriteLiteral("\n            <h2>");
#nullable restore
#line (16,18)-(16,38) 6 "D:\Century\Internal\MyProduct\MyProduct\aspnet-core\src\MyProduct.IdentityServer\Pages\Index.cshtml"
Write(CurrentUser.UserName);

#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
                    WriteLiteral("</h2>\n            <h5 class=\"text-muted\">");
#nullable restore
#line (17,37)-(17,54) 6 "D:\Century\Internal\MyProduct\MyProduct\aspnet-core\src\MyProduct.IdentityServer\Pages\Index.cshtml"
Write(CurrentUser.Email);

#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
                    WriteLiteral("</h5>\n            <div>\n                <strong>Roles</strong>: ");
#nullable restore
#line (19,42)-(19,78) 6 "D:\Century\Internal\MyProduct\MyProduct\aspnet-core\src\MyProduct.IdentityServer\Pages\Index.cshtml"
Write(CurrentUser.Roles.JoinAsString(", "));

#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
                    WriteLiteral("\n                <br/>\n                <strong>Claims</strong>: <br/>\n                ");
#nullable restore
#line (22,18)-(22,114) 6 "D:\Century\Internal\MyProduct\MyProduct\aspnet-core\src\MyProduct.IdentityServer\Pages\Index.cshtml"
Write(Html.Raw(CurrentUser.GetAllClaims().Select(c => $"{c.Type}={c.Value}").JoinAsString(" <br /> ")));

#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
                    WriteLiteral("\n            </div>\n        ");
                }
                );
                __Volo_Abp_AspNetCore_Mvc_UI_Bootstrap_TagHelpers_Grid_AbpColumnTagHelper = CreateTagHelper<global::Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bootstrap.TagHelpers.Grid.AbpColumnTagHelper>();
                __tagHelperExecutionContext.Add(__Volo_Abp_AspNetCore_Mvc_UI_Bootstrap_TagHelpers_Grid_AbpColumnTagHelper);
#nullable restore
#line 15 "D:\Century\Internal\MyProduct\MyProduct\aspnet-core\src\MyProduct.IdentityServer\Pages\Index.cshtml"
__Volo_Abp_AspNetCore_Mvc_UI_Bootstrap_TagHelpers_Grid_AbpColumnTagHelper.SizeMd = global::Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bootstrap.TagHelpers.Grid.ColumnSize._9;

#line default
#line hidden
#nullable disable
                __tagHelperExecutionContext.AddTagHelperAttribute("size-md", __Volo_Abp_AspNetCore_Mvc_UI_Bootstrap_TagHelpers_Grid_AbpColumnTagHelper.SizeMd, global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers.HtmlAttributeValueStyle.DoubleQuotes);
                await __tagHelperRunner.RunAsync(__tagHelperExecutionContext);
                if (!__tagHelperExecutionContext.Output.IsContentModified)
                {
                    await __tagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync();
                }
                Write(__tagHelperExecutionContext.Output);
                __tagHelperExecutionContext = __tagHelperScopeManager.End();
                WriteLiteral("\n    ");
            }
            );
            __Volo_Abp_AspNetCore_Mvc_UI_Bootstrap_TagHelpers_Grid_AbpRowTagHelper = CreateTagHelper<global::Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bootstrap.TagHelpers.Grid.AbpRowTagHelper>();
            __tagHelperExecutionContext.Add(__Volo_Abp_AspNetCore_Mvc_UI_Bootstrap_TagHelpers_Grid_AbpRowTagHelper);
            await __tagHelperRunner.RunAsync(__tagHelperExecutionContext);
            if (!__tagHelperExecutionContext.Output.IsContentModified)
            {
                await __tagHelperExecutionContext.SetOutputContentAsync();
            }
            Write(__tagHelperExecutionContext.Output);
            __tagHelperExecutionContext = __tagHelperScopeManager.End();
            WriteLiteral("\n</div>");
        }
        #pragma warning restore 1998
        [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]
        public ICurrentUser CurrentUser { get; private set; }
        [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]
        public IHtmlLocalizer<MyProductResource> L { get; private set; }
        [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]
        public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.IModelExpressionProvider ModelExpressionProvider { get; private set; }
        [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]
        public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IUrlHelper Url { get; private set; }
        [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]
        public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IViewComponentHelper Component { get; private set; }
        [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]
        public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IJsonHelper Json { get; private set; }
        [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.RazorInjectAttribute]
        public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper<IndexModel> Html { get; private set; }
        public global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary<IndexModel> ViewData => (global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewDataDictionary<IndexModel>)PageContext?.ViewData;
        public IndexModel Model => ViewData.Model;
    }
}
#pragma warning restore 1591
```

And here is the `index.cshtml` file that produces that file:

```
@page
@using MyProduct.Localization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using Volo.Abp.Users
@model IndexModel
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<MyProductResource> L
@inject ICurrentUser CurrentUser
<div>
    <abp-row>
        <abp-column size-md="_3" class="text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-user d-block" style="color: #12b900; font-size: 10em;"></i>
            @* ReSharper disable once Mvc.ControllerNotResolved *@
            <a abp-button="Primary" asp-controller="Logout" asp-action="Index" asp-area="Account">@L["Logout"]</a>
        </abp-column>
        <abp-column size-md="_9">
            <h2>@CurrentUser.UserName</h2>
            <h5 class="text-muted">@CurrentUser.Email</h5>
            <div>
                <strong>Roles</strong>: @CurrentUser.Roles.JoinAsString(", ")
                <br/>
                <strong>Claims</strong>: <br/>
                @Html.Raw(CurrentUser.GetAllClaims().Select(c => $"{c.Type}={c.Value}").JoinAsString(" <br /> "))
            </div>
        </abp-column>
    </abp-row>
</div>
```

And here is the associated `index.cshtml.cs` file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.RazorPages;

namespace MyProduct.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : AbpPageModel
    {
        public ActionResult OnGet()
        {
            if (!CurrentUser.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return Redirect("~/Account/Login");
            }

            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Another strange thing is that every time I double-click on the error to open the `Index.cshtml.g.cs` file, Visual Studio locks up and I have to kill the process and restart  it.

If you are familiar with MVC or with the ABP Framework, you should know that this same problem is occurring for each of my cshtml files.

How can I resolve these errors? Thanks.

Comment: Since I posted this, I discovered that the cshtml files I copied from the EasyCrm sample did not fully specify the namespace in the @ model declarations. Why this worked in the Volosoft solution, I have no idea. I corrected all of the declarations and the errors went away. However, the Index.cshtml file in the Pages root folder continues to generate this error even though I have corrected the @  model declaration. What gives? I go in and I delete the OBJ and BIN folders before running for building but I continue to get the error. Please advise.

Comment: I found it. It was in another project - MyProduct.IdentityServer. I now believe that the Cleanup Code feature may have removed the @ using directives from these files.